# Pick two colors from an Array

Tags: php, css

been building myself a website with a specific palette of five predefined colors, with the background-color being one of them. The CSS file is rendered using PHP, thanks to which I was able to get the following working (with placeholder colors):

```
<?php
  $bg_colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange');
  $bg_rand = $bg_colors[array_rand($bg_colors)];
?>
background-color:<?=$bg_rand?>;
```

Now the question is there a way to call the four colors that have been left out by array_rand? 
Let's say the background-color turned out to be green, how could I call specifically #1, #2, #4 and #5?

The reason being that these five colors will be used throughout the website, and an arbitrary div with the same background-color as the body background is a no-go in this case. How can I achieve that?

Comment: How will you have 4 backgrounds on one element?

Comment: I won't. One background color out of the predefined five, randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, while this isn't the cleanest option, by a long shot, you could just shuffle the array and then use the first result, leaving the following 4 to work with as you please.

For example:

```
<?php
$bg_colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange');
shuffle($bg_colors);
?>
background-color:<? echo $bg_colors[0]; ?>
```

This would leave the remaining 4 colours, randomly, in array values (1,2,3,4)

EG; $bg_colors[1], $bg_colors[2] etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions. I finally chose this one, because it gave me the required amount of control over the other colors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_splice()](https://www.php.net/array_splice) to get a random one. Then the array would only have the remaining colors

```
array_splice($bg_colors, $random_number, 1);
```

Edit: typo

Answer (score 0):

You could just suffle the array and get values one by one like this:

```
<?php
$bg_colors = array('red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange');
shuffle($bg_colors);
$bg_rand = array_shift($bg_colors);
```

Now you would have 4 colors left in array.

Also you could just make 5 color spesific css files and add one of those by random to the page. But then you would have as said only 5 different color schemas. Now that you could have 120 or something

Answer (score 0):

You could either remove a color after using it

```
$rand_index = array_rand($bg_colors);
$bg_rand = $bg_colors[$rand_index];
unset($bg_colors[$rand_index]);
```

Or save used colors in a 2nd array called `$used_colors` and then filter them out before selecting a random one

```
$available_colors = array_intersect($bg_colors, $used_colors);
$bg_rand = $available_colors[array_rand($available_colors)];
```